# When should you set the $GOPATH variable?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, gopath, gopls

Can anyone explain when to set $GOPATH? I know it's in the default, C:\Users\Username\go, location, but what if all my coding projects live in Z:<codelocation> ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable):

> The Go path is used to resolve import statements.
>
> The GOPATH environment variable lists places to look for Go code.
>
> When using modules, GOPATH is **no longer used for resolving imports**. However, it is still used to store downloaded source code (in GOPATH/pkg/mod) and compiled commands (in GOPATH/bin).

Assuming you're using modules, which you probably should be, the setting of GOPATH will not impact your projects regardless of where you put them. It only needs to be set *somewhere* so the Go tools have a cache to store libraries and binaries.